# How do I get length of list of lists in Java?

Tags: java, list

If I have a `List<List<String>>` data in Java, I can get the length of the first list via code:

```
int lengthData = data.get(0).size();
```

But how do I get the number of lists in the structure without traversing the list of lists to find out?

Maybe I've been a bit unclear. I have the structure:

```
List<List<String>> data
```

And I see that:

```
int i = data.size();
```

Will equal 1 because it is the root list. So what I want to know is how many sublists there are. Traversal of the structure like this:

```
for (List<String> l : data) {                     
     total ++;                
}
```

Only gives me a result of 1 which I find odd.

I have data of the form:

```
List 1 ==> 1, 2, 3, 4
List 2 ==> 3, 8. 9, 1
```

And so on where these are sublists of the root list.

Comment: You cannot. You have to traverse, or use a more sophisticated list that does the traversing for you...

Comment: You can't?  Is it that long a list that it's really difficult just to iterate over it?

Comment: If `data.size()` is returning 1, then you *don't* have two sublists. You have one. That's why iterating over it only gives one result too. Everything you've said points to a problem in your original data. I suspect if you try to come up with a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, you'll work out what's going wrong.

Comment: Yes. That was the problem. It has been solved now.

Answer (score 79):

Just use

```
int listCount = data.size();
```

That tells you how many *lists* there are (assuming none are null). If you want to find out how many *strings* there are, you'll need to iterate:

```
int total = 0;
for (List<String> sublist : data) {
    // TODO: Null checking
    total += sublist.size();
}
// total is now the total number of strings
```

Comment: I've tried this prior to posting. For some reason, this is not giving the correct result.

Comment: @Mr Morgan: I doubt that. Please post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @Mr Morgan, List.size() is what I would expect too. Can you provide a example of when it *doesn't* produce the desired result? Also, what concrete implementation are you using for the outer List?

Answer (score 6):

Java 8

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
            List<List<String>> stringListList = new ArrayList<>();
            stringListList.add(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"(0,0)", "(0,1)"} ));
            stringListList.add(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"(1,0)", "(1,1)", "(1,2)"} ));
            stringListList.add(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"(2,0)", "(2,1)"} ));

            int count=stringListList.stream().mapToInt(i -> i.size()).sum();

            System.out.println("stringListList count: "+count);
     }
}
```

Comment: Not going to work because the size() method is not a getter, i.e not getSize(). Which means for example in jsp we can't do simple thing like <% ${myList.size} %>. This is such a bane and I wondered why there was never any efforts to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

*count of the contained lists in the outmost list*

```
int count = data.size();
```

*lambda to get the count of the contained inner lists*

```
int count = data.stream().collect( summingInt(l -> l.size()) );
```

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TestClass {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listOLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    ArrayList<String> List_1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List_1.add("1");
    List_1.add("2");
    listOLists.add(List_1);

    ArrayList<String> List_2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List_2.add("4");
    List_2.add("5");
    List_2.add("10");
    List_2.add("11");
    listOLists.add(List_2);
    for (int i = 0; i < listOLists.size(); i++) {
        System.out.print("list " + i + " :");
        for (int j = 0; j < listOLists.get(i).size(); j++) {
            System.out.print(listOLists.get(i).get(j) + " ;");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

}

### I hope this solution gives a better picture of list if lists