# why there is no element in the list even after populating the list?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
package collectionwaliclass;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ArraylistWaliClass {

    public static List<String> list= new ArrayList<>() ;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //list= ;
    ArraylistWaliClass arraylistWaliClass= new ArraylistWaliClass();
                //adding the element to the existing list 
                int counter=0;
                /*while(counter++<10)
                {
                    arraylistWaliClass.addElement("new element"+counter, list);
                }*/
                //traversing the list in the arryaList
                list.forEach((x)->
                {
                    System.out.println(x);

                System.out.println("uff");
                });

                //deleting the list from the arraylist


    }
    public void addElement(String string, List<String> list)
    {
        list.add(string);
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through your code with a debugger to make sure that `addElement()` is actually being called?

Comment: It doesn't help that you've got commented out code, as well. Please provide a [mcve] which really demonstrates the problem.

Comment: A) see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846841/how-do-i-get-length-of-list-of-lists-in-java B) this is super basic stuff. Did you check out the existing documentation for more than a **second** to try to answer your question yourself? C) please turn to the help center and read how/what to ask here. It is not exactly nice to just dump some question and some messy, badly formatted code here ... to expect other people to spend their time to help you.

Comment: Where you are calling your `addElement` method?? why you have commented your `while` loop which will call `addElement` method?

Comment: apology for my silly que.....I have run the code for 10 times. now after adding the 10 elements to the list. ijuct commented the adding part of the code, just to check if the elements are actually there or not.

Answer (score 0):

because of scope definition, you are just adding elements to the parameter

```
List<String> list
```

in

```
  public void addElement(String string, List<String> list)
    {
        list.add(string);
    }
```

Comment: what should be the solution then ?

Comment: resolve the names... are you sure you need a lsit as parameter in the add method????

Comment: I just want, if i have added element to a list. it should be there untill an unless i delete that explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine if you just un-comment the while loop:

Output:

```
new element1
new element2
new element3
new element4
new element5
new element6
new element7
new element8
new element9
new element10
```

Code:

```
package collectionwaliclass;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ArraylistWaliClass  {

    public static List<String> list= new ArrayList<>() ;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //list= ;
        ArraylistWaliClass arraylistWaliClass= new ArraylistWaliClass();
        //adding the element to the existing list 
        int counter=0;
        while(counter++<10)
        {
            arraylistWaliClass.addElement("new element"+counter, list);
        }
        //traversing the list in the arryaList
        list.forEach((x)->
        {
            System.out.println(x);
        });

        //deleting the list from the arraylist
    }

    public void addElement(String string, List<String> list)
    {
        list.add(string);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, i know it is working fine, but the actual que is, after adding the element once. they should be present in the list. but after commenting the add part?