# How to get the size of a List in java

Tags: java, list

How to get the size of a List in java

for example, I have this list and I want to get its size which is 7

[16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22].

??

sorry I meant the size of a list of a big list.

Comment: did you try size()?

Comment: Copy and paste your exact title to Google.

Comment: yourList.size(), the list class has a size method one it, what type is that list stored as

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get length of list of lists in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846841/how-do-i-get-length-of-list-of-lists-in-java)

Comment: I mean the number of elements of a list which is inside the big list , like bigList.get(0).size();

Answer (score 1):

Good place to look for useful methods associated with List is documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html

'   size()
Returns the number of elements in this list.'

List myList = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5);

myList.size();

Comment: sorry , I mean the number of elements of a list which is inside the big list , like bigList.get(0).size();

Comment: Please provide some valid example.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that you have a List, with several arrays inside the list, I would cast the object when you get the array to an array then call `.length` like;

```
String[] stuff1 = new String[]{"1", "1", "1"};
String[] stuff2 = new String[]{"2", "2", "2"};
String[] stuff3 = new String[]{"3","3","3"};

List list = new ArrayList();
list.add(stuff1);
list.add(stuff2);
list.add(stuff3);

String[] find = (String[])list.get(1);

int length = find.length;
```

But you really should do some googling before asking such a fundemental question.